# Flutter: How to test a widgets who contains a StreamBuilder?

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, testing

I'm new on Flutter and I want to add Widgets tests to my app. But I have some problems and questions about widget tests a little more complex than flutter documentation.
Indeed i have a Scaffold widget with this body :

```dart
body: StreamBuilder<List<UserData>> (
        stream: DatabaseService().searchUser(searchValue),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && searchValue.length >= 3){
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/friends/search/details', arguments: snapshot.data[index]);
                  },
                  title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                );
              }
            );
          }
          return Center();
        },
      )
```

The first question is:

Is it necessary to test this StreamBuilder?

And if yes: **How can I mock the stream and test these widgets ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it necessary to test this StreamBuilder?**

This is subjective. Generally if there is anything that you feel is critical to the functionality of your app, then its better to write a test for it to ensure it works/behaves as expected always.

**How can I mock the stream and test these widgets ?**

There are tons of resources online to achieve this. Maybe have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/juwencheng/ae1f8e2f58ec9c92d2bf0a5d333e27d7)?

Comment: Thanks, I looked at this example, but the builder is defined in test, how can I get the builder of my Scaffold widget ?

Comment: You could mimic the similar code and then with `expect` verify the widgets.